# Create an In Line Table in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, unpivot

I am trying to write a query in AWS Athena that puts a selection of values into one column.

The query I have thus far is:

```
select (123, 456)
```

But that yields:

```
col0
{field0=123, field1=456}
```

The desired output is:

```
col0
123
456
```

Is there a way to do this? Maybe using unpivot?

Comment: What about just `UNION ALL`? i.e. `Select 123 Union all select 456`

Comment: While this isn't technically what I wanted, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I mean.. that doesn't make any sense but glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following query

```
select * from (VALUES(123),
                     (456)) as t("col0")
```

Output:

```
#   col0
--------
1   123
2   456
```

If you want to have multiple columns in the table you can do it like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES(1, 'a'),
            (2, 'b'),
            (3, 'c')) as t(id, name)
```

Output

```
#   id  name
-------------
1   1   a
2   2   b
3   3   c
```